Maven's enforcer that checks for duplicate classes ignores automatic resolution of dependencies with different versions
I recently found out that Maven automatically resolves versions of packages, if they are conflicting. maven; how to break backwards compatibility?
For example, if dependency A requires a transitive dependency named Foo versioned 1.0 and dependency B requires a transitive dependency named Foo versioned 2.0, and dependency A & B are used in a project - version 2.0 will be loaded automatically as it's the higher version.
I have 2 issues:

In the event that 2 versions of the transitive dependency (i.e. Foo) are actually not backward compatible, could this break things in dependency A?
In Maven's enforcer, you can enforce a check on duplicate classes. https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html
Since Maven automatically resolves conflicting transitive dependency versions by using the highest version, does this mean there are actually many 'hidden' conflicts that are masked? Since there could actually be conflicts of versioning within the same transitive dependency.

Initially, I used maven-shade-plugin to package my transitive dependencies in one .JAR file. However, as I didn't shade some dependencies properly, they were picked up by the duplicate classes checker.
After removing them from the .JAR completely, I realised that the transitive dependency got upgraded automatically and the duplicate class checker failed to pick up on this conflict, which made me wonder why this was happening.
For example, dependency A and B both requires Foo (a transitive dependency), but a different version. Initially, Foo is packaged within dependency A (incorrectly shaded), while Foo is not packaged within dependency B. The error picked up by the duplicate class checker is as follows:
[ERROR] Found in: [ERROR] dependencyA.jar:1.0.0:compile (uses Foo.jar version 1.11.0) [ERROR] Foo.jar:1.8.0:compile
However, after moving Foo out of dependency A, it gets upgraded automatically and hence is not caught by the duplicate class checker. Isn't this automatic upgrade quite dangerous?

version 2.0 will be loaded automatically as it's the higher version That is not correct. The version number itself is not relevant for selecting a dependency. The distance between the dependency and your project is the factor which makes the decision...

@khmarbaise yep, thanks for the correction. In that case, there will still be forward / backward version compatibility issues between transitive dependencies?
